# evaluating mathematical expression in titanium javascript

Tags: javascript, titanium

i'm using titanium studio.
I've a mathematical expression to evaluate. 
for example I've this mathematical expression.

```
var expr='9+4*6/3';
```

i don't want to evaluate it step by step like first i'll be doing multiplication then devision etc.
is there any faster way to solve or is there any function in MATH class in titanium which can give the solution of an expression.
like

```
var result=MATH.func(expr);
```

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if eval is available in Titanium, but eval(expr) should work in normal circumstances.

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066824/safe-evaluation-of-arithmetic-expressions-in-javascript) for other ideas on how to do it without eval

Comment: Figured that might be the case, but wanted to check :) Did any of the libraries mentioned in the linked thread work out for you?

Comment: yes i also tried sample code of github that he mentioned but there was an error in 'test.js' file on second line.I think this module is for web not for titanium studio.