# Javascript/PHP Custom math formula

Tags: javascript, php, math, formula

can we use math formula from other variable/database?
example:

```
var x = 7;
var formula = '+';
var y = 10;
```

I mean that variables will output = `17` (7 + 10);

but how to implement this formula using Javascript/PHP?

Comment: @hakre: how about javascript version?

Comment: Please use the search. Also if you look for javascript, you should not tag as PHP. - possible duplicate of: [Safe evaluation of arithmetic expressions in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5066824/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example you could do this:

```
var x = 7;
var formula = '+';
var y = 10;
z = eval(x+formula+y);  // 17
document.write(z);
```

But `eval` is a big problem for security, and you really shouldn't use it. If you could give more detail on what you're trying to achieve it might be possible to suggest an alternative.

Comment: thanks ur the winner for Javascript version :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP Version

use `eval()` in php to run a php code segment:

```
<?php
$x = 7;
$formula = '+';
$y = 10;
$expression = '$result = ' .$x . ' ' . $formula . ' ' . $y . ";";
echo $expression, "\n";    // $result = 7 + 10;
eval($expression);         // run the code
echo $result, "\n";        // ouput 17
```

### [see the result of the code here](http://codepad.org/9L2rcspM)

Comment: thanks ur the winner for PHP version :)

Answer (score 0):

In php you can use as below. You can avoid `eval` in this way.

```
$x = 7;
$formula = '+';
$y = 10;

switch ($formula) {

case "+" : $res = $x + $y;
          break;

case "-" : $res = $x - $y;
          break;

.
.
.
.


}

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in PHP and javascript(with a little modification). Also I'd recommend not using eval what so ever because of security reasons.

```
function math($x, $y, $sign){
    switch($sign){
        case '+':
            return $x + $y;
        case '-':
            return $x - $y;
        case '*':
            return $x * $y;
        case '/':
            return $x / $y;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
$x = 7;
$formula = '+';
$y = 10;
echo math($x, $y, $formula);#returns 17
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be evaluating textual formulas repeatedly with 'eval(),' you may wish to store it within a function - like this:

```
var formula = "x + y";
var func;
eval("func = function(){return" + formula + "}");
```

At this point, you could call 'func()' at any time when variables x and y exist within the given scope. For example:

```
var x = 7;
var y = 10;
var answer = func();
```

The value of answer would then be '17.'