# Replace var^power with pow(var,power)

Tags: java, javascript, regex, string

I'm writing a math app in Java that uses Javascript for scripting/input.
I want to be able to enter, say, `x^2` and have Java replace that with `pow(x,2)` before sending to the JavaScript parser.  How can I do this type of replacement?  There might be multiple different such expressions in one code snippet, which might be one or more lines.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages with almost nothing in common except for some syntax they both inherited from C. Do not confuse them.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm not.  My Java app uses a JavaScript parser (`javax.script.ScriptEngine`) for evaluating entered expressions in JavaScript.

Comment: I see. Well, ultimately the only bulletproof way to do this is to write a JavaScript parser that is able to recognize your extra operator. Anything less than this will have caveats where the substitution doesn't do the right thing. For example, if `x^2` appears in a string literal, you don't want to replace it.

Comment: You need to take associativity and precedence into account - therefore you need to write a parser.

Comment: if you mandate parens around replaced subsets, you _might_ be able to get away with naive substitution, we would need to know more about the input possibilities. if not a parser is a sure fire, if complicated, way to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what this app is for, but if there's any decent chance that you'll have to handle more complex expressions including parenthesized ones, I wouldn't start down the regex path, except perhaps if you need a simple prototype for a demo.  You'll probably ending up just making the regex more and more complicated and then having to throw the whole thing out anyway.

Comment: You *cannot* reliably do this with regex. It is simply not powerful enough. You need a real math parser. See: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).

Answer (score 3):

You should fork the esprima JS parser to add the `^` operator with appropriate precedence etc. Then walk the parse tree, identify where it is used, and do the lexical substitution. This link might be useful: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/math-evaluator-in-javascript-part-2.html. Not quite sure how you'll call this from your Java program, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Or, the parser in http://mathjs.org/ apparently already supports `^`, so you could use that. Or, there is http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/ which also appears to support `^`. Or http://jsep.from.so/, "a tiny JavaScript expression parser".

Related SO question: [Safe evaluation of arithmetic expressions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066824/safe-evaluation-of-arithmetic-expressions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I'm not sure how much complexity you're expecting, but if you want it to be able to handle some tricky expression, you might as well use parser library.

---

Supposing you're talking about javascript and you're replacing string input, do the following.

```
"x^2".replace(/(.*)\^(\d+)/, "pow($1, $2)")
```

Comment: i would add more context to your RegExp to handle spaces, negatives, etc.

Comment: What if `a^b` appears in a string literal?

Comment: What if the user enters more complicated things, like `x^0.5` or `(x+y)^(z-4)`? (Or even `x^y^2`.)

Comment: Also, make it `/g`, to match multiple occurrences..?

Comment: nothings perfect, but the answer can be made better with some extra attention, and might be satisfactory depending on usage. it's going to be a WHOLE lot more complicated if RegExp fails to pan out.

Comment: @dandavis Expression strings **are** complicated.  Regexes are nice but they cannot solve every problem.  Regexes do not deal well with things like nested parentheses.

Comment: @ajb: it depends on use, but a multi-pass, multi-rx workload can handle many nested situations with atomic operations. i completely agree RXs is not a silver bullet, but if all that needs done is 1 or more operations like OP described, it doesn't sound to me like it's categorically beyond the pay grade of an RX. I knew some unix scripters would could seemingly move mountains with an RX.

Comment: @dandavis RX cannot parse regular languages. You can hack it by applying a regex multiple times, but there will always be some edge case where it fails to do the right thing -- operator precedence and associativity being a huge example of this. If you do manage to get it right with a regex that can be applied multiple times, then you'll have created such an unmantainable monster that it would have been better just to write a JS parser anyway.

Comment: @dandavis yeah, and I'll bet their regexes were about as readable as Egyptian hieroglyphics... :) :) :)

Comment: @dandavis tl;dr version is that "can" and "should" are different things. Can you do this with regex? Maybe, but unlikely. Should you. No. Hell, no.

Comment: @cdhowie: i just worry that a custom parser could be a bridge too far and that a few hours of debugging RegExp might be enough for this situation, but neither of us know enough to make that call. there's such a thing as over-building, even in a world of mostly under-built crap... but i 100% agree parser is a more professional and expandable option. it just might be as likely to force project abandonment as work...

Comment: @dandavis The amount of work to do this right in regex is incredible. I say this as someone with extensive experience both with regex and hand-writing recursive descent parsers. The parser will be easier to write, easier to get correct, easier to debug, and easier to extend later if OP wants to add other operators. I can virtually guarantee that if you spent less time on a regex than you did on a parser that it would be extremely easy to find a case where the regex fails to do the right thing.

Comment: i have updated my ans. it may works many cases but not all cases. you may try this.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**
**update:**  it is possible some cases

```
var re = /(?![\+\-\*\/\(\)\^\s])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/gm;
var str = 'w*x^2 +5^9';
var subst = 'pow($1,$2)';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/rG3tR3/2)

**And better reference for math calculation**.http://mathjs.org/

**example & output**

```
// expressions
math.eval('1.2 * (2 + 4.5)');     // 7.8
math.eval('5.08 cm to inch');     // 2 inch
math.eval('sin(45 deg) ^ 2');     // 0.5
math.eval('9 / 3 + 2i');          // 3 + 2i
math.eval('det([-1, 2; 3, 1])');  // -7
```

Comment: What if the input is `y^3 + x^2`? The question said "There might be multiple different such expressions in one code snippet".

Comment: And 32*x^2 should become 32*pow(x,2), not pow(32*x,2).

Comment: What about `a^(b^c)` or `(a^b)^c`? Good luck making those substitutions correctly with just regex.

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik Hint: You can't. Regex doesn't do recursion like that; it cannot parse regular languages.

Comment: @cdhowie Note that I'm using Java for the replacement, so if recursion can't be done with a Regex, maybe a recursive function with Regex could work.

Comment: i think, for math calculation, use mathjs is better and ref: [http://mathjs.org/](http://mathjs.org/)

Comment: @SkylarMT Very unlikely. Bear in mind that as I said earlier, you have to take into account that you might be in the middle of a string literal for example. Detecting this kind of situation in regex is very hard. It would be easier to write a correct parser than a correct regex.

Comment: forking the old jsmin routine lets you easily avoid string literals without the complications of a full parser...

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik Repeat very slowly after me: **YOU CANNOT PARSE EXPRESSIONS WITH REGEXP**. For every case you come up with that works, I can easily come up with a counter-example that doesn't work. This is parsing theory 101.

Comment: i think, it is not possible to use only regex. it may possible to use any function with regex. but i can't more try..