# Javascript Compare function with text values

Tags: javascript

I am having some javascript coding/comparing issues. `alert(myfn)` gives me `78>=99.35`. How can I use this in function now?

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=g.ClientID%>').innerHTML != '') {
    var myvar = '';
    var myfn = '';
    myvar = document.getElementById('<%=a.ClientID%>').value + document.getElementById('<%=g.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
    //alert(myvar);
    myfn = myvar.replace('&gt;', '>').replace('&lt;', '<');
    alert(myfn);
    if (myfn) {
        alert("t");
    }
    if (78>=99.35) {
        alert("m");
    }
    //alert(Boolean(myfn));
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific , please

Comment: `eval('78>=99.35')` gives you `false`, however it costs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe evaluation of arithmetic expressions in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066824/safe-evaluation-of-arithmetic-expressions-in-javascript)

Comment: You should use one the many libraries available to evaluate expressions. See the question suggested as a duplicate for ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval` function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

> The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument.
>
> If the argument is an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If
>   the argument is one or more JavaScript statements, eval() executes the
>   statements.

```js
alert(eval("78>=99.35"));
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to do only arithmetic evaluation, then you can use following code to make `eval` safer (as @JosephMalle point it out)

```js
var exp = "78>=99.35";

exp = exp.replace(/[^0-9<>=\-()\.]/g, "");
// or 
exp = exp.replace(/[^0-9<>=\-()\.+*/|&\?%:]/g, "");
// which also includes bitwise, logical 
// and conditional (ternary) operators
alert(eval(exp));
```

Comment: This would be dangerous because any valid JavaScript that gets into the `eval` function will be run.

Comment: @JosephMalle It also stops JS engines' optimization.