# Calculate numerical string by using javascript

Tags: javascript

My string is `10+20/3*87/234` how can I calculate the result without using eval function in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Without using eval or a constructor function in Javascript , how can I calculate arithmetic in a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31600121/1529630)

Comment: Why not eval? Which is the syntax of your math expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function constructor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

```
function calculate(fn) {
  return new Function('return ' + fn)();
}


alert(calculate('10+20/3*87/234'));
```