# simplify equations/expressions using Javacc/jjtree

Tags: parsing, javacc, equations, simplification

I have created a grammar to read a file of equations then created AST nodes for each rule.My question is how can I do simplification or substitute vales on the equations that the parser is able to read correctly. in which stage? before creating AST nodes or after? 
Please provide me with ideas or tutorials to follow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you equations are something like simple polynomials over real-value variables, like   `X^2+3*Y^2`

You ask for two different solutions to two different problems that start with having an AST for at least one equation:

- How to "substitute values" into the equation and compute the resulting value, e.g,  for X==3 and Y=2, substitute into the AST for the formula above and compute `3^2+3*2^2` --> `21`
- How to do simplification: I assume you mean *algebraic* simplification.

The first problem of substituting values is fairly easy if yuo already have the AST.  (If not, parse the equation to produce the AST first!)  Then all you have to do is walk the AST, replacing every leaf node containing a variable name with the corresponding value, and then doing arithmetic on any parent nodes whose children now happen to be numbers; you repeat this until no more nodes can be arithmetically evaluated.  Basically you wire simple arithmetic into a tree evaluation scheme.

Sometimes your evaluation will reduce the tree to a single value as in the example, and you can print the numeric result [My SO answer shows how do that in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600121/how-do-you-write-an-arithmetic-expression-parser-in-javascript-without-using-ev/31621205#31621205).  You can easily implement this yourself in a small project, even using JavaCC/JJTree appropriately adapted.

Sometimes the formula will end up in a state where no further arithmetic on it is possible, e.g., `1+x+y` with x==0 and nothing known about y; then the result of such a subsitution/arithmetic evaluation process will be `1+y`.  Unfortunately, you will only have this as an AST... now you need to print out the resulting AST in order for the user to see the result.  This is harder; [see my SO answer on how to prettyprint a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832412/compiling-an-ast-back-to-source-code/5834775#5834775).   This is considerably more work; if you restrict  your tree to *just* polynomials over expressions, you can still do this in small project.  JavaCC will help you with parsing, but provides zero help with prettyprinting.

The second problem is much harder, because you must not only accomplish variable substitution and arithmetic evaluation as above, but you have to somehow encode knowledge of algebraic laws, and how to match those laws to complex trees.    You might hardwire one or two algebraic laws (e.g.,  `x+0` -> `x`; `y-y` -> `0`) but hardwiring many laws this way will produce an impossible mess because of how they interact.

JavaCC might form part of such an answer, but only a small part; the rest of the solution is hard enough so you are better off looking for an alternative rather than trying to build it all on top of JavaCC.
You need a more organized approach for this:  a [Program Transformation System (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).  A typical PTS will allow you specify
a grammar for an arbitrary language (in your case, simply polynomials),
automatically parses instance to ASTs and can regenerate valid text from the AST.  A *good* PTS will let you write source-to-source transformation rules that the PTS will apply automatically the instance AST; in your case you'd write down the algebraic laws as source-to-source rules and then the PTS does all the work.

An example is too long to provide here.  But [here I describe how to define formulas suitable for early calculus classes, and how to define algebraic rules that simply such formulas including applying some class calculus derivative laws](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html?site=StackOverflow).

With sufficient/significant effort, you can build your own PTS on top of JavaCC/JJTree.  This is likely to take a few man-years.  Easier to get a PTS rather than repeat all that work.