# Evaluate math expression given in string format

Tags: javascript

How do I parse and evaluate a mathematical expression in a string?

```
<input type="text" id="expression_text" value="Enter equation.....">
var exp_string=$("#expression_text").val();
//"exp_string=4+6*9+3"
```

Comment: Just dont use `eval()`

Comment: Possible Duplicates: [Safe evaluation of arithmetic expressions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066824/safe-evaluation-of-arithmetic-expressions-in-javascript) or [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `eval()`, is just not save. Use a library like http://mathjs.org/ to accomplish your task.

Comment: First, please read comments under vol7ron's answer. Second, suggesting a library can be a double edged sword. It can go against you. Third and more importantly, *only-link* answers are considered bad. Please try to explain how and why.

Comment: fourth - this doesn't answer the question. if i asked you how to add 2 plus 2 and you say, don't use a watermelon, that's a non-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had some difficulty in understanding what you were after.  As I understand it, you have a string that is a math assignment, that you want to return both the string and the calculated value to the backend.

There are several ways to do this.  The obvious way if you have control over your inputs is to use `eval()`, though a quicker version would be to avoid `eval` and use a `Function` constructor:

```js
// I've replaced what would be returned by `val()` with the expected string
var text_input='exp_string=4+6*9+3';       //$("#expression_text").val();

// Performs the calculation and assigns the value to a global `exp_string` variable
Function(text_input)();

// Example of what can be used and what the variables hold
console.log(`${text_input} will equal ${exp_string}`);
```

**Important!**
I would be remiss if I did not bring attention to the security concerns regarding `eval` or `Function` contructor.  As mentioned in the comments below, `eval` is said to be "evil" for a reason.  With lack of sanitation and control over inputs, it opens your front-end to dangerous XSS attack and other exploits.  For this reason, it's better to be safe than sorry and shy away from its use.

That being said --*and this is partially opinionated*-- it isn't unusable.  It serves a purpose and is efficient at what it does, but it is important to research the security risks and know when it is applicable.