# Get answer from string in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm getting this value in variable but i want it's answer.

for first it should return **0.5** and for second it should return **1** .

**1*1/2**

**2*1/2**

Can any one help me to get answer from this text. 
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe evaluation of arithmetic expressions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066824/safe-evaluation-of-arithmetic-expressions-in-javascript)

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. jQuery doesn't do math (we'll it uses JavaScript to do math)